# generating random key as unique id(running out of random numbers.)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I have a scenario where I need unique random 5 or 6 digit numbers to be stored as booking Id of my customers.
So I simply create random numbers using.

```
var booking_id_customer = Math.floor(Math.random()*900000) + 10000;
```

Than store them in my mongodb as

```
    booking_id_customer: {
    type: Number,
    index: { unique: true }
},
```

But I am running out of numbers now, I don't have idea about how to handle this but the requirements are 5 or 6 digit random numbers only. How to handle this situation any hint will be a great idea.

Comment: Ids are mostely used as autoincrement. But if you only can have 5 or 6 digit numbers you'll have a limit, soon or later...

Comment: Are you close to using 900k records?

Comment: yes, and since i am generating random numbers its throwing a lot of error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no solution. Architectural flaws are the most difficult to solve. Somebody were need to think about limit when designed the system.

Simplest thing you can do now, is to add more numbers. Also, if you have limit by length only, you can use mix of numbers and letters.